# How can I search for a specific item on Blacksmith?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was looking in the [list of blacksmith recipes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/) and found some interesting items, but when I started looking for them, it took some time to find.

How can I create specific searches in-game for items in my blacksmith? for example by name or by level.

Comment: Searches... where? On the Battle.net Game Guide site? In the in-game blacksmith menu? On the auction house? And can you give an example of what you mean by "specific search"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't

There is no search feature built in, however your items are sorted by item type first, and then by required level (highest level on top)

So to find an item, simply go to the item category (Bracers, Crossbows, Shields, etc), and then the approx level of the item you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

At this point there is no chance to search items in the UI. If you want to know when you get this recipes... then you just have to farm a lot. I found my first recipe in Nightmare at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the required mats can tell you what level you'll be crafting for. I'll only keep on my toon the mats of crafting in the level that i'm currently at. I'll filter the BS to show only Have Mats which will show me the items in that range. Unfortunately with the current UI, that's what you'll have to live with.